# Documentation for the Android app development using laetst ARCore SDK without using Sceneform

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore

I have to develop android application using ARCore latest SDK without using Scenefor. Currently Google not providing any proper step by step documentation for the ARCore kotlin.
Latest ARCore SDK using OpenGL to render object, it's complex to understand ARCore's sample project?

Can anyone please provide document or guidence for app development using ARCore.

I have tried to modify ARCore's sample project to render my model but i'm not able to render my model.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but why isn't the community version of sceneform available to you? Is it an imposed challenge or a development decision?